# How can I convert inMemoryUploadedFile into string to pass it over an api?

Tags: django

I want to pass user uploaded images into an api form my view

How can I convert the inMemoryUploaded file into a string and pass it over an api and convert it back to image?

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code would be helpful, otherwise we are guessing at intent.

You can `base64.b64encode` the image binary, which will give you text.

[Base 64 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)